# Как сделать асинхронное выполнение запросов к серверу. Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

Я хочу создать сервер, при запросе GET на который в консоль сервера будет выводиться дата и время. А через определенный интервал завершить ответ сервера и вернуть клиенту время.

Я делаю это вот таким образом.

```js
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const getDateToUTC = () => (new Date).toUTCString();

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        const interval = setInterval(() => console.log(getDateToUTC()), 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            res.end(getDateToUTC());
        }, 5000)

    }
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Но! При многоразовом обращении к серверу функция будет срабатывать только когда будет даны все предыдущие ответы.

Т.е. я открываю две вкладки в браузере и перехожу на `localhost:3000`.
Стараюсь быстро переходить, ну наверное, будет разница в 500 мс между запросами.
И ожидаю получить и ответы с сервера с таким же интервалом.

По факту же, второй запрос начинает обрабатываться только после того, как завершится первый, т.е. через 5 с в данном примере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы запросы работали асинхронно?

Comment: "По факту же, второй запрос начинает обрабатываться только после того, как завершится первый, т.е. через 5 с в данном примере" Нет. С чего вы взяли?

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин.

Comment: А что на скрине? Вы одновременно открыли две вкладки, но обработка второй только через 5 секунд началась? Какая версия nodejs? А то у меня на 8 такой проблемы нет.

Comment: Да, именно! последняя v10.9.0

Comment: Проблема в самом Хроме (: Я оформил ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Занятно. В Firefox всё нормально работает. А в Хроме запрос не отправляется на второй вкладке, пока не получен ответ на первый запрос.

Судя по логам, это проблема не node.js, а именно браузера.

На en SO это [обсуждалось](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource):

> Yes, this behavior is due to Chrome locking the cache and waiting to
>   see the result of one request before requesting the same resource
>   again. The answer is to find a way to make the requests unique. I
>   added a random number to the query string, and everything is working
>   now.

Хром лочит кеш и ожидает ответа на первый запрос. Чтобы это обойти, нужно сделать запрос уникальным. К примеру, можно открывать не **http://localhost:3000** два раза, а **http://localhost:3000/?id=2** и **http://localhost:3000/?id=1**

Если вы эти запросы посылать планируете из консоли/программно, то можно в хедеры запроса добавить `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform`, это тоже должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Вы правы!

Comment: @Igor рад помочь )